# AWS : Bitnami : UNYSON : Cannot create temporary directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitnami

I am facing the below issue-

WordPress 5.7.2 <> Tyring to install the required extension for UNYSON framework...and getting below error -

Install Extension Install theme compatible extensions

Downloading the "Shortcodes" extension...

Cannot create temporary directory:

Cannot create temporary directory: Return to the Extensions page

Tried - sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins

Still no luck...Please help.

Comment: You could try manually uploading the plugin with FTP. Seems like a permissions issue, perhaps it also needs escalated privilege's wherever its trying to make the tmp directory.

Comment: No I am not uploading the plugin using FTP. Unyson PLUGINs were downloaded and installed using the WordPress plugin interface. I  tried all the suggested solutions related to privileges nothing seems to be working.

The funny part is the Same theme with UNISYN framework is working fine on another hosting platform. Not sure what's wrong with UNISYN and AWS and BITNAMI image.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to fix the error using by adding the line.

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', realpath(ABSPATH . './wp-content/'));
```

under the lines,

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );}
```

in wp-config.php.

Final code looks like this

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );}
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', realpath(ABSPATH . './wp-content/'));
```

Comment: My problem was that I put `define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', realpath(ABSPATH . './wp-content/'));` at the very end of `wp-config.php`. Didn't know it had to go right after the `ABSPATH` definition. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's reset the WordPress permissions:

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/wordpress
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /bitnami/wordpress/
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/bitnami/wordpress
sudo chmod -R g+w /bitnami/wordpress/
sudo chmod 644 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-config.php
```

Can you install the WordPress' plugin now?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Just go to the linux's command line, access the config archive using:

```html
vim /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-config.php
```

Then find this piece of code:

```js
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {

define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );

}
```

Press ' i ' to insert a new line of code right below that one, and write:

```js
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR',realpath(ABSPATH.'/wp-content/'));
```

As a result you must have:

```js
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */


/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {

define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );

}

define('WP_CONTENT_DIR',realpath(ABSPATH.'/wp-content/'));


/**

 * The base configuration for WordPress

 *
```

Then just **press 'ESC'** to stop editing, **then :W** to save - or write - the code, and **lastly :Q** to quit the file.

Now you must be able to run the installation/ update successfully